# very slow and unreliable boot with dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have ubuntu in dual boot and it used to work. after an upgrade the boot has become very slow (20minutes?). it is slow before and after login, and often just hangs.
also: i'm a newbie and did not even succeed in installing the tools to scan boot...

Comment: Please show the results of `systemd-analyze blame` which should be installed by default.

Comment: Which version you're running ? When booting to ubuntu was it stuck on graphical logo or showing console messages ?